# permission denied while collect static django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I had project with django + guicorn + nginx ([this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04))

I delete virtualenvironment and get a new one, everything works correctly but, when I try to use command:

```
source projectenv/bin/activate

folder1/project/manage.py collectstatic
```

I got an error:

```
-bash: folder1/folder/manage.py: Permission denied
```

even when I try:

```
folder1/folder/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

-bash: folder1/folder/manage.py: Permission denied
```

What should I do to make this virtualenvironment work correctly?

Comment: `python folder1/project/manage.py collectstatic` / `folder1/folder/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Or make sure the `manage.py` executable: `chmod +x folder1/project/manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: thank you python3 folder1/project/manage.py collectstatic  works properly

Answer (score -1):

```
python3 folder1/project/manage.py collectstatic
```

worked properly

thanks to comment falsetru